# recover partition after resize

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I booted from HBCD, tried to resize the partition and finally it failed. The first partition is ok, but the second is missing. When I click on the second, Windows wants to format it. If I use a recovery software it founds all the files.

Is there any way fo fix the lost partition without formatting or recovering?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Partition Find and Mount and it found my partition intact (all file names and directory structure are ok). I just mounted it and backing up the partition.

Maybe it helps you.

I also want to know a alternative way to fix the partition, without backing up and recreating the partition